# How to get data with json result for searchable dropdown list?

Tags: jquery, json, dropdown

i'm using this jquery searchable dropdown list. But i want to bind cities with my json data. How can i do this?

my sample: searchable dropdown list

```
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var country = ["Australia", "Bangladesh", "Denmark", "Hong Kong", "Indonesia", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "South Africa"];
                $("#country").select2({
                  data: country
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>DropDown with Search using jQuery</h1>
        <div>
            <select id="country" style="width:300px;">
            <!-- Dropdown List Option -->
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my data from database

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '/Home/GetCities'
    }).done(function (jsonObj) {

        $("#country").select2({
            data: jsonObj // here it is
        });
    });
```

my tables has ID and

i want to show cities or other datas in searchable dropdown list

Comment: *my tables has ID and City

Comment: Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: I solved the problem.